# Why is the code between <head> tags added to <body> tags

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html code as follows [HTML CODE](http://pastebin.com/UEuNfCPg)

The problem is that if the code is printed to browser the contents inside the `<head>` tags are printed inside the `<body>` tag at the beginning of them i know surely it is a  tag somewhere not closed correctly but i see no errors. I think someone will see the coding error in my code! Thank's in advance for the help i get!

Comment: Add some more details like your web service, server details etc

Comment: and which browser is doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by "printed to browser"? Is it something other than just browsing to the page normally?

Comment: @blasteralfred apache webserver but this is a simple html code that is not necessary in the source code the title and etc. are between head tags but in the code inspector there are after the body tag
Ibu I am using google chrome borwser Google Chrome 21.0.1180.83 build 152131 Windows 7
Guffa i am using it with php so with the echo function!

Comment: Is that the code as the browser sees it, i.e. what "View Source" shows?

Comment: this probably needs a screenshot

Comment: Guffa that what is on pastebin is the view source option (ctrl+u)
@ImreL here is the screenshot [screenshot](http://i50.tinypic.com/2nrivl.png)

Comment: How are you echoing this HTML?  Is there any PHP before it? Is PHP echoing it?

Comment: Rocket here is the php code [php code pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ezJ8YhH5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<!DOCTYPE` needs to be the 1st thing on the page.  Lose all the white space before it.

The file in your pastebin starts with: `0D 0A EF BB BF`.  If you can't read hex, that's `\r\n` (a new line) followed by a UTF-8 byte order mark.

Comment: That is only a copy error the page is without spaces before the '<!DOCTYPE' tag

Comment: Are 100% sure?  Even a single space before the doctype will cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Yes sure here is the screen with the view source option [screenshot](http://i48.tinypic.com/2qny2yu.png)

Comment: The code in the screenshot probably still contains the byte order mark at the start. It is invisible. And although a BOM *is* allowed at the very start of a file, there might be some other control character before it, and then it is a problem. So please post a URL that lets people retrieve the actual data. Screenshots won’t help much to analyze invisible characters. – Chrome is known to behave the way described in the question when there is anything at the start of the document that could be interpreted as non-whitespace character data.

Comment: Roket is right. Your PHP files are probably in UTF8 with BOM. Make sure you have `<?` on a first line in every file and that php files in UTF8 dont have BOM

Comment: The problem was that i was working with the editor notepad++ in which the encoding was set to utf8 and this program is inserting a byteorder mark i've set the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM and now it's all okay! Thank's for the help! Have a nice evening all!